# Node Red MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-visualization, node-red, mlab

I have sensor data from MongoLab to Node-RED and I want visualize this data using Node-Red dashboard in form of a gauge or chart. 
Data from the mongoLab collection looks like this:

```
[{"_id":"5947e34de8fef902920defd8","sensorId":"5947340048225508","value":34,"date":"2017-06-19T14:44:29.000Z"},{"_id":"5947e34e6737e202b54f0a62","sensorId":"13359295204302776","value":25,"date":"2017-06-19T14:44:30.000Z"},{"_id":"5947e352e8fef902920defdc","sensorId":"5947340048225508","value":37,"date":"2017-06-19T14:44:34.000Z"},{"_id":"5947e3536737e202b54f0a66","sensorId":"13359295204302776","value":24,"date":"2017-06-19T14:44:35.000Z"}]
```

I want to visualize the values based on the sensorId...or is there any way I can be able to visualize this data using Node Red.[image: node-red screenshot]

[image: api request]

[image]

The function node is using the following javascript

```
msg.headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"};
return msg;
```

My intention is to visualize the sensor value on the ui_gauge or chart.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I managed to push data from 4 different sensors ie temp-humidity, light, air pollution and sound to mongoLab on cloud where each sensor is a collection on its own in the database. From there I am using a node-red mongodb in node, which fetches data from mongoLab. This node is connected to a HTTP request node which uses a GET method and then another HTTP response node. See the link that I have added above.

Answer (score 2):

Make a gauge/graph for each of the unique data steams you want to reflect in the UI/dashboard,

Then you'll need to double the output lines to another function that passes this information to the msg.payload, and then from that function, tie it to the corresponding dashboard gauges.

A gauge will obviously show the last value sent, while a graph will show you a history. May need to tweak the visual layout of the dashboard gauges/charts to show more data, to your liking.

Flow Chart Example[image]

Your code might look something like this in the new forked function that is then tied to your gauges:

```
  msg.payload = msg.value; 
  return msg;
```

or you can use a switch, that then breaks the values to multiple outputs, that then each output goes to a corresponding gauge to reflect the data.

Flow Chart Example Using Switch[image]

I really hope this helps.

Comment: @PMerlet, That explains why the pics weren't showing... Ty for the edit.